# How to deploy .EAR Application from JDeveloper to Weblogic Domain directly from Oracle JDeveloper

Tags: deployment, weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a JDeveloper Project that is in .ear file. I loaded it into JDeveloper as new application and I can see the whole project. I also have a weblogic domain where this application files in .WAR and .ear are deployed. The application is up and running ok.

What I want is to be able to deploy the project directly from the JDeveloper.

How can I do this?

I already tried to deploy the application (Deploy to Application Server) -> Created a new Application Server (Connection was a success) -> Deploy to selected instances in the Domain (Selected the server where the application is deployed - NOT the Admin Server) and Deploy as a Standalone Application.

I don't know if the previous steps were correct and neither if this is the correct way to do what I want to achieve.

Comment: If you already have an EAR file, why do you want to add another step and use JDeveloper in the middle instead of directly deploy using Weblogic Console or Enterprise Manager

Comment: The reason why I wanted to deploy the application was to test it. Because I can not run the page normally on JDeveloper (I don't know why), so I thought about deploying it and check if would run. And yes I already made a deploy from the weblogic console manually and it work, but as I am making changes on JDeveloper I would like to be able to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKeDZ8_0BlQ
Define a connection to your application server, and then use the application->deploy option to deploy your application.